# SELECTing Related Rows Based on a Single Row Match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table running on Postgres SQL 9.5:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|ID |  trans_id  |   message   |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | 1234567    | abc123-ef   |
| 2 | 1234567    | def234-gh   |
| 3 | 1234567    | ghi567-ij   |
| 4 | 8902345    | ced123-ef   |
| 5 | 8902345    | def234-bz   |
| 6 | 8902345    | ghi567-ij   |
| 7 | 6789012    | abc123-ab   |
| 8 | 6789012    | def234-cd   |
| 9 | 6789012    | ghi567-ef   |
|10 | 4567890    | abc123-ab   |
|11 | 4567890    | gex890-aj   |
|12 | 4567890    | ghi567-ef   |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

I am looking for the rows for each `trans_id` based on a `LIKE` query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE message LIKE '%def-234%'
```

This, of course, returns just three rows, the three that match my pattern in the `message` column. What I am looking for, instead, is all the rows matching that `trans_id` in groups of messages that match. That is, if a single row matches the pattern, get all the rows with the `trans_id` of that matching row.

**That is, the results would be:**

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|ID |  trans_id  |   message   |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | 1234567    | abc123-ef   |
| 2 | 1234567    | def234-gh   |
| 3 | 1234567    | ghi567-ij   |
| 4 | 8902345    | ced123-ef   |
| 5 | 8902345    | def234-bz   |
| 6 | 8902345    | ghi567-ij   |
| 7 | 6789012    | abc123-ab   |
| 8 | 6789012    | def234-cd   |
| 9 | 6789012    | ghi567-ef   |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

Notice rows 10, 11, and 12 were not `SELECT`ed because there was not one of them that matched the `%def-234%` pattern.

I have tried (and failed) to write a sub-query to get the all the related rows when a single `message` matches a pattern:

```
SELECT sub.*
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT trans_id FROM table WHERE message LIKE '%def-234%'
    ) sub
WHERE table.trans_id = sub.trans_id
```

I could easily do this with ***two*** queries, but the first query to get a list of matching `trans_id`s to include in a `WHERE trans_id IN (<huge list of trans_ids>)` clause would be very large, and would not be a very inefficient way of doing this, and I believe there exists a way to do it with a single query.

Thank you!

Comment: `select * from table
  where trans_id in (select distinct trans_id from table where message like '%def234%');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job I think :

```
WITH sub AS (
    SELECT trans_id 
      FROM table 
     WHERE message LIKE '%def-234%'
)
SELECT *
  FROM table JOIN sub USING (trans_id);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, trans_id, message
FROM (
   SELECT ID, trans_id, message,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE message LIKE '%def234%') 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY trans_id)  AS pattern_cnt
   FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE pattern_cnt >= 1
```

Using a `FILTER` clause in the windowed version of `COUNT` function we can get the number of records matching the predefined pattern within each `trans_id` slice. The outer query uses this count to filter out irrelevant slices.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b6fa4/6)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
WITH trans
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT trans_id 
   FROM t1 
  WHERE message LIKE '%def234%')
SELECT t1.*
 FROM t1,
      trans
WHERE t1.trans_id = trans.trans_id;
```

I think this will perform better. If you have enough data, you can do an explain on both Sub query and CTE and compare the output.